zsh alias still exists after deletion [MACOS]
I previously worked at a company who heavily used KDB (q) in their workflow. That's why I used this official article to install it. Using 5th step (Step 5: Edit your profile), I added this alias alias q='QHOME=~/q rlwrap -r ~/q/m64/q' to my .zshrc file, and sourced it.
After a while, I decided to remove kdb from my system, so I deleted all the necessary files and removed the line alias q='QHOME=~/q rlwrap -r ~/q/m64/q' from my .zshrc, and again I used source to activate this change.
But for some reason, the alias q is still appearing to exist, even after that (sytax highlighting of my terminal also proves that). Now, hovewer, after executing q, I'm getting the error because I removed the necessary files for it to run properly:
❯ q                                                                                                        
rlwrap: error: Cannot execute /Users/*****/q/m64/q: No such file or directory

Can somebody please explain what's going on? How do I completely and permanently get rid of this alias?

unalias q. Explanation here (for bash, but in this case it also applies to zsh): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483407/alias-not-updated-after-using-source-bashrc

source does not "activate changes", it runs the commands in a file. There used to be a command in your .zshrc to create q as an alias, so when you sourced the file it created that alias. The file no longer contains that command, so sourceing it doesn't create that alias anymore... but it doesn't delete it either, so the alias is still set in your shell. Either unalias it or just create a new shell that doesn't have the alias.

I used unalias q, stopped all terminals, reloaded my computer, - nothing helped. It is still there =(

Try type q, make sure that q is indeed an alias. If it's still showing up in a new shell, then it is being set in one of the startup files.

I have this output after typing type q:
q is an alias for QHOME=~/q rlwrap -r ~/q/m64/q
It seems that it is indeed a valid alias.
But there is no a single string that could cause that in the startup files that you provided. Anyways, thank you

Instead of sourcing your .zshrc - which really does not make much sense - you could have created a zsh sub shell, which starts of with no aliases. Of course you inherit the environment from the parent shell, but this seems to be irrelevant to your problem.

Ok, so the thing is - I also used oh-my-zsh - and it seems that the alias was simply present in one of its custom setup scripts called .oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh. So I removed it from there, reloaded the shell and it finally gone.
Thanks Gairfowl and Gordon Davisson, your support is appreciated!
